# Django: form.as_p not showing up in rendered template

Tags: python, django

Django:
I've passed form.as_p into my html template however it doesn't show up in the browser. What am I doing wrong??

models.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("studentform/", views.CreateStudentForm, name="CreateStudentForm"),
]
```

forms.py:

```
class StudentForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = [
            'student_name',
        ]
```

views.py:

```
def CreateStudentForm(request):
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }

    return render(request, 'main/studentform.html', context)
```

studentform.html:

```
<form>

{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='Save' />

</form>
```

I do not understand as to why     {{ form.as_p }} does not work. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) to generate a form from a model in django. So your StudentForm will become

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Student
       fields = [
           'student_name',
       ]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

here if you want to use the form provided by django first of all i have to tell django that brother , i want to use your form , so you need to write the form code in side the forms.py  and forms.py also tells django's model to create a space in the model to hold the form's data, after creating form.py use the form created in views.py and if the data is valid make an entry in the model or database using the form.save() method , but if do not created the forms.py so do not show the form in side views.py and not show our html file so{{ form.as_p }} this is not work

i hope this answer was helpful to you